# How to infer union type of all passed parameters

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create a function whose return type is a union of the passed types of all the parameters. This is as far as I got:

```js
const getRandomParameter = <T extends []>(...args: T): T[keyof T] => {
  const randomIndex = getRandomInt(0, args.length);
  return args[randomIndex];
}
```

Desired:

```js
const randomParameter = getRandomParameter(1, false, 'a', 'b');
typeof randomParameter; // 1 | false | 'a' | 'b'
```

Does anybody know how to properly type the `getRandomParameter` function to infer its return type as a union of all its parameters?

Answer (score 1):

```
const getRandomParameter = <T extends unknown[]>(...args: T): T[number] => {
  // code here
}
```

Comment: With this solution, `randomParameter` is inferred as `string`, not `"a" | "b" | "c"`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `T` the array type, use `T` as the type for the elements:

```
const getRandomParameter = <T>(...args: T[]): T => {
```

then `T` will be inferred as a union:

```
// getRandomParameter<"a" | "b" | "c">("a", "b", "c");
const randomParameter = getRandomParameter('a', 'b', 'c');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygJQIZgCYgLYAVUBOq2SCBMAvDADwAqAfABQB0rhcEAXDLQNoC6ASm61K9GAG8AsACgYMUJFhFMOAJKYEAD0rwkaVdg1RGABgA0MdhGYAbBGDhQAFoIDcs+QSQBXAmCsCDl4VLCNNLX4PGQBfWVlFaBhQnHwiEigyXUQUdDC04lICRgByVBLLEoAjCpgS4BL3WQB6Zvl5AD0AfiA)

Comment: This is close! But doesn't work with non-strings [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygJQIZgCYgLYEkywC8MAFNgJZgBcMYArtgEYIBOANDNqgB431OsAlDEIA+GAG8AsACgYnSiJgBZVFAAWAOmAJyAGzKVBAblnyu3Jao2aAZnpAgWZHibMwWSOizAq1W+0dnay0WdCxsEmEAKlILGABaBTBhAGpktxkAX1lZUEhYRBRwnAAFVDDsJFYlAB4AFVESTRaKuAgaeoBtAF1BTpFxaTkYfOgPErxMBEtiIrRMHHwoEgAGDjaITT0EMDgNTPlPKG9fTa6wxamMGZ7TbNyZMdhLiPLK6pYARiV5yffUFUoKwSLZUHoIAgOAByVDQmGMaGZAD0yPk8gAegB+PLgcagFieYDFK4AoGsL40MEQhAwAA+MFh0PpjMRSiZ91R6Jg2MezwmpIqgM+ACZfkgFm8heTnF8YXCEUjOWj0bynnjYASiSSpR9gSwRTQfgymSzoWziF9ldzsUA)

Comment: @micDropper In version 5.0.0 we have const generics which makes things a lot simpler: https://tsplay.dev/mL34AN - for now I'm trying to find how you would get around it in version 4.